# Proof with functions and inverse - Spivak

Tags: calculus, inverse

> [image]
>
> [image]

How does he know that $f^{-1}$ is one-one? Doesn't he have to prove that? Or is he applying his first theorem in the chapter to $f$? That is $f$ is a function if and only if $f^{-1}$ is one-one?

EDIT: Probably a very stupid question, but can someone actually show me the case for $-f$? Or is Spivak simply saying that we can take it for granted (and I believe this because it make sense) and not actually try to prove $-f$ is increasing?

Comment: Since $f$ is increasing, it is one-one. By suitable a restriction , it admits an **inverse**. Inverses are by definition one-one.

Comment: Did you try making some drawings, for example?

Comment: No I know it is true and I drew some straight lines to convince myself this is true, but I just thought he should prove it too.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Note that Spivak does not limit inverses to one-one functions. "It is popular to abstain from this procedure [of reversing all the ordered pairs that comprise the function] unless _f_ is one-one, but there is no particular reason to do so -- instead of a definition with restrictive conditions we obtain a definition and a theorem. [...] Theorem 1: _f^-1_ is a function if and only if _f_ is one-one."

Comment: @Joe Ah, now I remember, yes. =) Maybe he wanted to emphasize the importance of injectiveness.

Comment: @sidht : It's straightforward that if $f$ is decreasing then $-f$ is increasing, but you need to think through how this implies that $f^{-1}$ is decreasing.  How many steps you write out explicitly is partly a matter taste and partly a matter of how many steps you are able to see in your head without putting them down on paper.  Spivak's use of the word "consider" suggests that he believes there's something you need to think about in this proof.  Perhaps I went overboard in my answer, but I thought it worth pointing out that you need to think about what it means to invert the function $-f.$

Comment: No I am fully aware that the case $-f$ works. I was just wondering how does one go about *proving* it through $-f$.

Comment: Dear sidht, is there lacking in the answers you had? I noticed you didn't yet choose a right answer, so I suppose you're not satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you may retrieve the one-to-one property from a similar reasoning as the one used in the proof.

Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is not one-to-one. This means there exist $a < b$ such that $f^{-1}(a) = f^{-1}(b) = k$. Hence $f(k) = f(f^{-1}(a)) = a$ and $f(k) = f(f^{-1}(b)) = b$, that is $a = b$. But this can't be because we supposed $a < b$.

Hence $f^{-1}(a) > f^{-1}(b)$ or $f^{-1}(a) < f^{-1}(b)$, which one? See Spivak's proof.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the additional question in your edit: if $f$ is decreasing then $f(b)<f(a)$ whenever $b>a.$  Therefore $-f(b)>-f(a)$ whenever $b>a.$  Hence $-f$ is increasing.  By the previous result, the inverse of $-f$ is therefore increasing.  This implies that $f^{-1}$ is decreasing.

To understand the final step, we need to ask $``$what is the inverse of $-f?"$  If $\eta$ is the negation map, $x\mapsto -x,$ then $-f=\eta\circ f$ and so the inverse of $-f$ is $f^{-1}\circ\eta^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ\eta$ since the negation map is an involution.  So $f^{-1}\circ\eta$ is increasing.  This means that $f^{-1}(\eta(b))>f^{-1}(\eta(a))$ whenever $b>a.$  But this means that $f^{-1}(-b)>f^{-1}(-a)$ whenever $b>a$ and, letting $b'=-b$ and $a'=-a,$ that $f^{-1}(b')>f^{-1}(a')$ whenever $-b'>-a'.$  Consequently $f^{-1}(a')<f^{-1}(b')$ whenever $a'>b'.$  Hence $f^{-1}$ is decreasing.

Comment: What I actually want was to show that $-f$ is increasing and this in turn show $f^{-1}$ is decreasing or $-f^{-1}$ is increasing.

Comment: @sidht : I thought that was the goal too, so we are somehow not communicating well.  How can I clarify my answer?

Comment: Repeat Spivak's proof, but replace $f$ with $-f$ was what I was thinking. Then at the very end step, you will have to negate the negatives by $-(-f) = f$ which should show $f^{-1}$ is decreasing

Comment: @sidht : that's a different strategy and also works: assume $-f$ increasing and let $a<b.$  If $f^{-1}(a)<f^{-1}(b)$ then $-b=-f(f^{-1}(b))>-f(f^{-1}(a))=-a$ and so $b<a$, contradiction.  Therefore $f^{-1}(a)>f^{-1}(b).$  My method was to *use* the existing result rather than repeating its proof: $-f$ increasing means $(-f)^{-1}$ increasing.  But that means $f^{-1}$ decreasing.  I thought it important to spell out that last inference.

Comment: I was thinking of $-f^{-1} (a) < -f^{-1}(b)$

Comment: @sidht : if you are still in doubt about the proof, can you spell out more of the details?  Your inequality is, of course, equivalent to the conclusion of the first proof in my comment above, but I'm not sure whether your proof is otherwise the same, or differs in some respect.

Comment: Crazy question. While I was imitating the proof, I wanted to write *Suppose $-f$ is increasing. Let $a < b$. Then $-f^{-1}(a) < -f^{-1}(b)$* but that clearly won't give me the correct result. I was just wondering why can't i do that? I know it's a vague question

Comment: @sidht : Not sure how the last line in your proof is modeled after Spivak's, or how it was meant to be obtained.  But it does lead to the correct conclusion, doesn't it?  If $-f^{-1}(a)<-f^{-1}(b)$ then $f^{-1}(a)>f^{-1}(b),$ which, since $a<b,$ makes $f^{-1}$ a decreasing function, as desired.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your issue, but the main point of my post was that one has to distinguish $-f^{-1}$ from $(-f)^{-1}.$  The former is the function whose value at $x$ is the additive inverse of $f^{-1}(x),$ while the latter is is the inverse of the function $-f.$  To see the distinction, consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=e^x.$  Then $f^{-1}(x)=\log x$ and $-f^{-1}(x)=-\log x.$  On the other hand, $-f(x)=-e^x.$  The inverse here is given by $(-f)^{-1}(x)=\log(-x)$.  Observe that $-f^{-1}$ and $(-f)^{-1}$ don't even have the same domain.